# What is the name of this mechanical puzzle with two G-like hooks interlocked?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

I don't know the name of this puzzle. See the photo below. I've already searched for G puzzle and Hook puzzle.

[image: picture of puzzle with two twisted pieces of metal interlocked together]

Comment: Search for `Metal Wire Puzzle`

Comment: This question is much more useful than a lot of "guess what I'm thinking" posts.

Answer (score 9):

After much scrolling, I found this puzzle on [Rob's puzzle page](http://robspuzzlepage.com/tanglement.htm#hardsetsmod), which lists hundreds of entanglement puzzles. It's a great page, definitely consider checking it out.

This puzzle is from the (now defunct) Parlor Puzzles brand, in its Set 2. The puzzle is called "the Link".

Here are the pictures from Rob's puzzle page:

[image: A boxed set of five metal entanglement puzzles, brand name Parlor Puzzles. The leftmost puzzle is the puzzle in question.]

The puzzle in question is the leftmost puzzle in the box. Here's a standalone picture:

[image: Standalone picture of the puzzle in question, glowing on a black background.]